# How many rows will be fetched from cursor with my code

Tags: postgresql

I am new to plpgsql, and I am excercising cursor.

I have following simple code,

```
create or replace function func_cursor_2() 
returns setof numeric as $$
declare
    cursor1 CURSOR for select empno,ename, job from emp;
    r record;
begin
    open cursor1;  
    loop  
        fetch from cursor1 into r;      
        exit when not found;
        return next r.empno;
    end loop;
    close cursor1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


select func_cursor_2()
```

With `fetch from cursor1 into r`,

1. It looks to me that I am fetching the result rows one by one?
2. Is there way to specify 100 rows for one fetch from cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with a cursor at all. This can be done in 1 statement.

```
create or replace function func_cursor_2() 
  returns setof numeric
 language sql
as $$
    select empno 
      from emp 
     limit 100; 
$$;
```

However, the above will not return consistent results. To generate consistent you will need to add `order by empno` and perhaps [offset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-limit.html) depending on your exact needs.

Note: Not Tested.

Comment: thanks,  i am exercising plpgsq1 and cursor.

Comment: Then see the documentation for [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) to get the available options. Take a good look at the `ABSOLUTE` and `FORWARD` options.